# +12V main voltage tolerance as power input for an industrial PC motherboard

Tags: pcb-design, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, ldo

Regarding the following circuit, we have two main devices:

1. [MAX8792](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v93doye4ug74w8n/MAX8792.pdf?dl=0) Step-Down Controller.
2. [LT3065](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yu7u9pgialqv12h/3065fa-6.pdf?dl=0) LDO.

[image]

I want to know the minimal "+12_Main" voltage that can be applied and still make this circuit work. The reason for my question is that I want to approximate the tolerance for the +12V_Main that could be applied by the customer. The +12_Main is supplied from external AC adapter. "+12V_Main" is Vin LT3065 LDO and TON input in MAX8792 step-down controller.

Here is my analysis:

- MAX8792 must have 5V for VDD. (Bias supply, could we use a different voltage?)
- For  LT3065 5V output, 5.6V < Vin < 45V.
- According to MAX8792 Table 1, for Vout = 3.3V @ 6A, 7V < Vin < 20V for TON = 332kOhm.
- I need at least ~10A for MAX8792 (U3) 3.3V output in order to suffice for the rest of the design devices.
- For the MAX8792, DH - LX  = VGS for high side  FDMS7682 transistor. According to the datasheet, VGS = DH - LX = -0.3V to (VBST + 0.3V), assuming VBST=VDD=5V when it's high, VGS = 5V.
- For the MAX8792 high-side FDMS7682 transistor it looks like for VGS = 5V the graph goes crazy with high current.

What did I miss here in order to keep analyzing right so I can find the tolerance for VIN = +12V_Main?

Comment: Have you tried to approach this problem from the other side? What range of voltages can you expect from power supplies, how much can they deviate? Surely 12V supply shouldn't output some 9V, I think? There should be a reasonable limit to their deviation (it's a proposition to do a little research in that area)

Comment: The issue here is not the 12V output deviation itself, but more of inserting wrong voltage by customer, or the unavailability of 12V supply.

Comment: @Xhero39 typically manufacturers are not worried about end users providing the wrong voltage. You tell them what voltage it uses and that's that. If they don't provide the right voltage that's their problem. It's very rare for a device to list a range of voltages instead of just one.